# Open google map from my website

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a list of addresses in database. I can show google from these addresses in my website but I want to make a link from these addresses. When user clicks on address It will open google map in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just done this for a client. If you take the following php generated link:
    `<?php echo 'http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q='.$placestring.'&amp;aq=&amp;sll=&amp;sspn=&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear='.$near.'&amp;t=h&amp;z=12'; ?>`

`$placestring` in my code is simply the address, put through a `htmlentities()` routine to ensure it is a safe url. The `$near` variable can be used to avoid doubt if your addresses are all within a certain area - i.e. if all of the addresses are in London, you could use London as the `$near` variable. This helps google to provide a better match. If you have postcodes (in the UK) or a lat/long then this will massively help.